# Ошибка 'Entry' object is not callable

Tags: python, tkinter

В окне создала кнопку,которая должна создать окошко-напоминание,текст для которого берется из Entry.Но при нажатии окно не появляется и полказывается ошибка.

```
class Child1(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent  # << сохраняем ссылку на родительское окно
        self.init_child1()
        # vv перехватываем кнопку закрытия окна чтобы вернуть назад родительское окно
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: (parent.deiconify(), self.destroy()))
        parent.withdraw()  # << прячем родительское окно
    def init_child1(self):
        self.title("Создать экранное уведомление")
        self.geometry("800x600")
        self.config(bg="#CCFFFF")
        entry_text = ttk.Entry(self)
        entry_text.place(x=200, y=10)
        label_title = tk.Label(self, text="Введите название", bg="#CCFFFF")
        label_title.place(x=100, y=10)
        btn_noti = tk.Button(self,text="Создать экранное уведомление",command=self.cli(entry_text()))
        btn_noti.place(x=100,y=90)
    
    def cli(self,entry_text):
        import time
        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M")
        time.sleep(2)
        note =entry_text.get()
        time.sleep(1)
        cli_ = tk.Tk()
        cli_.title("Напоминание")
        root.geometry("300x300")
        tk.Label(cli_, text=current_time).pack()
        tk.Label(cli_, text=note).pack()
        cli_.mainloop()
        cli_(self)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cобытие на кнопку лучше в данном случае навешивать через **лямбду**(отложенный вызов, а не результат вызова `self.cli(entry_text())`. Ну и `entry_text()` - не может быть вызвано.

В методе `cli` я заккоментил `cli_(self)` так как это равнозначно `tk.Tk()()` что разумеется не имеет смысла и вызывает ошибку.

В общем: будьте аккуратны со скобочками `()` :)

```
from tkinter import ttk
import tkinter

class Child1(tkinter.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)
        #self.parent = parent  # << сохраняем ссылку на родительское окно
        self.init_child1()
        # vv перехватываем кнопку закрытия окна чтобы вернуть назад родительское окно
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", lambda: (parent.deiconify(), self.destroy()))
        parent.withdraw()  # << прячем родительское окно
    def init_child1(self):
        self.title("Создать экранное уведомление")
        self.geometry("800x600")
        self.config(bg="#CCFFFF")
        entry_text = ttk.Entry(self)
        entry_text.place(x=200, y=10)
        label_title = tkinter.Label(self, text="Введите название", bg="#CCFFFF")
        label_title.place(x=100, y=10)
        btn_noti = tkinter.Button(self, text="Создать экранное уведомление",command=lambda:self.cli(entry_text))
        btn_noti.place(x=100,y=90)
    def cli(self,entry_text):
        import time
        current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M")
        time.sleep(2)
        note =entry_text.get()
        time.sleep(1)
        cli_ = tkinter.Tk()
        cli_.title("Напоминание")
        root.geometry("300x300")
        tkinter.Label(cli_, text=current_time).pack()
        tkinter.Label(cli_, text=note).pack()
        cli_.mainloop()
        #cli_(self) 

root = tkinter.Tk()
n = Child1(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `В коде закралась опечатка ttk.Entry(self) вместо tk.Entry(self).` - это не опечатка, это класс Entry из модуля tkinter.ttk

Comment: @insolor спасибо, был не в курсе, так как редко ткинтером пользуюсь писал свою реализацию